# How to retrieve data from the database in the View Pager concept?

Tags: android, database, android-viewpager

I have implemented the view pager concept and retrieved one data.
now,i want to retrieve the other data from the data base to the pages i swipe to..

```
xyz= db.tablename(id);
for (int i = 0; i < xyz.size(); i++) 
{
data1 key= xyz.get(i).get("data1");
    data2 key=xyz.get(i).get("data2");
    data3 key=xyz.get(i).get("data3");
}
```

Now I get these values on one screen and being repeated for other swiped views.

Whereas,i want the values to change for the **other layouts of swipe views**.

I have declared the **View Pager** coding after setting the text for the particular field.

My View Pager coding is this..

```
pageadapter adapter=new pageadapter();
vp.setAdapter(adapter);
vp.setCurrentItem(0);
```

What should i do?

**I tried implementing the View Pager coding(above mentioned coding) within the FOR loop but neither the content layout is seen nor the swipe features work.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fragments with ViewPager then in your fragment class Make a cursor with a Where statment where the id is the id of the ViewPager. And populate your listview with that cursor. This way all your database entries will get sorted according to the id of the ViewPager. Make an extra column in the database named ViewpagerID or anything if you need.

The raw query can be like

SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE ViewpagerID = ?

where ? can be your viewpager id.

Comment: Then I'd recommend to use it. If each of your View has a listview then you can control all the listviews through on class. Because you'll be using only one fragment class. I am also working with this kind of implementation.